# Connection Response on GoDaddy Hosting (Returns 500 Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, pdo

Localhost picture working when it comes in AJAX see the picture below

[image: Localhost]

But in LIVE it returns 500 internal server error

[image]

We're done by overriding the httpd.conf by .htaccess with

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>
```

and by putting

```
header("Connection: keep-alive");
```

in db.php still the `Connection: close` still there.

We used PDO connection string. And last thing if the process used INSERT INTO statement it gives the error of 500 internal server error but in SELECT and UPDATE everything works fine. Can someone give an advice to fix this problem?

Comment: Take a look into your http servers error log file to learn what the actual issue is.

Comment: We already looked at that it says there is something wrong with the query but in localhost it works fine and in the previous hosting also. We don't know why in godaddy hosting returns error.

Comment: Well, then I suggest that you add the precise error message to the question. If there is something wrong and throws an error then you have to deal with that error and not guess around trying arbitrary other things. _What is the precise error message_? "Something" does not help, has never done so.

Comment: #0 /home/host/public_html/php/exec/functions.php(316): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/host/public_html/php/exec/register-exec.php(26): addUser(Array)
#2 {main}
  thrown in /home/host/public_html/php/exec/functions.php on line 316

This is the error that you are looking for @arkascha. We don't know why it gives us an error with something like that. We tested it both local and the previous hosting.

Comment: That is _part_ of an ecxeption back trace, not the error message. Please add the full error information _to the question itself_. Do _not_ add additional information in comments here.

Comment: So the error is that we can't register or we can't execute any insert statement in database but the statements works fine.

Comment: I cannot see why you come to that conclusion, nor do I see the full error message added to your question. Sorry.

Comment: Check whether php broken, problem could be using php versions , you may used undefined functions

Comment: @arkascha Usually php fatal error causes 500 errors

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam Sure, that is obvious. But still the way to solve such issue is _to read the precise error message, understand it and then solve the issue_. There is _no_ sense in panicing and playing guess work.

Comment: Sometimes I faced this issue because I used functions that are not restricted on that server or advanced PHP version's functions on that low PHP version server.

Comment: @arkascha I just gave a thought, I didn't tell that he should not check the error log.

Comment: First step is to actually read the precise error message. It is there, but the OP refuses to look at it, apparently. There is no sense in distracting the OP.

Comment: You are right. first, should check the error log.